# Use CSS with Lazy Load images loaded by using "data-original="

Tags: jquery, css, image, lazy-loading, center

i have a few images loaded with Lazy Load and i have to center them in the middle of the page.

So i have the standard Lazy Load plugin with

```
data-original="img/products/a001.jpg"
```

that loads a image that has to be centered and

```
src="img/loading.gif"
```

that has to be centered as well.

```
<img class="lazy img-centered img-responsive" data-original="img/products/a001.jpg" src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
```

I am using the following classes: lazy img-centered img-responsive with the following CSS:

```
.img-centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-responsive {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

Unfortunately the classes do not work as they where suppose to so how can i lazy load the images while centering them? I prefer to use CSS instead of JS, if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you link your page or a fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, the page is here http://opal.eu5.org/

Comment: Anybody? i hate this crazy load plugin :S

Comment: What element precisely in your page is not centered as you want ?

Comment: http://opal.eu5.org/img/products/a001.jpg , is the background of a div and is loaded with lazy load by using data-original. It is displayed from left to right, the problem is that if the user has a monitor with a resolution greater than 2000 the background wont be centered.

Comment: Extended my window (FF34 on Windows 7) to about 2200px and all the pictures are still centered :)

Comment: Nice, it seams that you are right, i have done something right after all. I have tested with http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//opal.eu5.org/&w=3000&h=600&s=1 . But there is still a problem, i took those photos with a camera lens that is very sharp in the middle and not so sharp on the edges and the images are not centered when the size of the screen is not larger than 2000 :D. That is why the not-so-sharp part of the picture is displayed instead of the center which is sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment, if your images are set as a background-image, you can try

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

This should keep the middle of your picture aligned with the middle of your element

Comment: Actually is not set as background-image but it is a background because there are another divs on top of it :D. The only css attached to the html is .img-centered and .img-responsive.